# Write method countVowels to take a string and return the amount of vowels

Tags: java

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input the string: ");
        String str = in.nextLine(); 

        System.out.print("Number of  Vowels in the string: " + countVowels(str)+"\n");
    }

   public String countVowels(String count) {

}
```

sorry but im very new to java and coding and trying to find a way to create a vowel counter but I seem to struggle with creating one ive tried looking up many answers but cant find one.

Comment: step 1: learn the difference between `java` and `javascript` - you don't want to be writing `javascript` in a job interview for a `java` coding position. `const countVowels = s => s.match(/[aeiou]/gi).length;`

Comment: HINT:  `s.charAt(n)` gives you the character at position `n` in string `s`.  You can then compare that character to `'a'`, `'e'`, `'i'`, `'o'`, `'u'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public int countVowels(String str)
{
   int vowelCount = 0;


   for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
   {
      if (str.toLowerCase().toCharArray()[i] == 'a' | str.toLowerCase().toCharArray()[i] == 'e' | str.toLowerCase().toCharArray()[i] == 'i' | str.toLowerCase().toCharArray()[i] == 'o' | str.toLowerCase().toCharArray()[i] == 'u')
      {
          vowelCount++;
      }
   }


   return vowelCount;
}
```

and if you want to include 'y', just add another comparison to the if statement

Comment: It told me that the non static method countVowels cannot be referenced static context .

Comment: Try changing `public int countVowels(String str)` to `public static int countVowels(String str)`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String countVowels(String count) {
    int Vowelcount = 0;
    String[] arr = count.split(" ");

    //looping through string array
    for (int i = 0; i <= arr.length - 1; i++) {
        //looping through each character in the next element
        for (char ch : arr[i].toCharArray()) {
            //checking if ch == to vowels
            if (ch == 'e' || ch == 'a' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u' || ch == 'i') {
                //add counts number of vowels for every string array index
                Vowelcount += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return Integer.toString(Vowelcount);
}
```

This should work just fine... I've split your words in the input string into a string array.